# the meaning of "*'s worth of"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is a sentence:

> Stork will be talking about his knowledge of vision, optics and computers——an entire **30-page CV's worth of scientific achievements**——has let him look into Vermeer's light, and discover how closely it matches reality.

I don't quite understand the meaning of "'s worth of " in this sentence. I think it means be full of in this sentence. However, according to my knowledge, it doesn't have this meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an idiom.

The relevant meaning in the Oxford English Dictionary is "2b. In extended use: the amount or quantity of something (material or immaterial) that is associated with, corresponds to, or lasts for a specified period of time, a given space, etc."

So "30 pages' worth" means "an amount of text that would fill 30 pages". Extending this idiom, "an entire 30-page CV's worth of scientific achievements" means "enough scientific achievements to fill an entire 30-page CV".