# What is the difference between "five days' work" and "five days' worth of work"?

Tags: meaning, difference

What is the difference between these two constructions:

> a) I've done five days' worth of work.
> b) I've done five days' work.

Example (a): I've done five days' worth of work in only two days!
Example (b): Great! Thanks to you, my five days' work goes down the drain!

Do they mean the following:

a) I have done as much work as I normally do within five days' time.
b) The amount of work that I have done within five days.

Comment: There is a nuance difference, but not without a context of time in the example a). You can do five days' worth of work in three days if you're working extra hard or extra long hours.

Comment: kaipmdh, I edited my question and added more context.

Comment: Related but not a duplicate: [{days / days'} worth of stuff?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/221210/9161), [the meaning of “*'s worth of”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/148219/9161)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would understand the two expressions just as you said.   Live examples:

> How to Complete a Week’s Worth of Work in One Day [source](https://www.robertplank.com/a-week-of-work/)

A week's worth of work clearly means "the amount of work that would normally take a week"

> Some have advocated for four days of work, followed by 10 days of lockdown.  [source](https://www.weizmann-usa.org/news-media/in-the-news/four-days-of-work-followed-by-10-days-of-lockdown-could-help-prevent-another-wave-of-infections/)

This clearly refers to an actual length of time.

However these division aren't rigid:

> Shortening the work week could mean axing important tasks as five days of work are crammed into four. [source](https://www.smh.com.au/business/small-business/a-four-day-work-week-sounds-nice-but-here-s-the-real-deal-20191119-p53bys.html)

So you must always read in context

Comment: Thank you, James!